# Get Display Name from Account Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I have used SPServices to get a user profile by their name, and in the process, I wish to display their supervisor's name as well.  I can pull this name from the user's object, but the supervisor is stored in the format of:

```
 domain\[8 character name]
```

How can I get the supervisor's full display name from his account name for a cleaner display in my form.  Doing so with javascript/jquery and SPServices would be preferred. This is likely easy, but I haven't been able to find the code to accomplish this looking around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to store the domain\username in a variable and make a call to the GetUserProfileByName operation to then get the managers name.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetUserProfileByName

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
  async: false,
  AccountName: yourmanagerVariable,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    //foo
   }
});
```